# Is it possible to uncorrupt a Dead Island save on the PS3?

Tags: ps3, dead-island

I have played this game twice, both times making it to about 80 percent through the main game. Both times that I turned the game off (making sure especially the second game not to do so when it was saving), it corrupted my saved file. Is there anyway to still play that file, or do I have to start over AGAIN?

Comment: Bravo for playing it again. I would have （╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻. Also, you could probably try quitting more often to facilitate more frequent saves. Perhaps playing through 80% in one sitting is causing the issue?

Comment: Pro-tip: Save file corruption is caused by save file size. Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/622414-dead-island/60399291

Answer (score 1):

You will have to start over again. Due to the "closed" nature of consoles, you can't directly access save files / points.